# How to change the parent portal template in dnn?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want to change the parent portal template. means site child portals contains catalook Modules and i want to show it in the parent portal. how can i change the parent portal template in dnn?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are actually needing to change is the admin skin. If you go into your Site Settings (under the Admin menu) and expand the Appearance section, you will see Drop Down Lists where you can select the Portal Skin and a separate one where you can select the Edit Skin (or Admin skin depending on the version of DNN). I think changing the Edit skin will do what you need.

If not, you'll need to log in as Host (or another Super User account) and go to the Host Settings page. Again you'll need to expand the Appearance section and select your desired skin for the Host Skin and/or Edit skin.